# Wrong election end date after extending nomination period

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

There's a [moderator election](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/election) going on on Bicycles Stack Exchange, and according to the [homepage](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/), it'll end in two days (2018-11-27 20:00:00Z):

[image]

However, the election page itself states it's going to end in *five* days (2018-11-30 20:00:00Z):

[image]

This is probably caused by [extending the nomination period due to a lack of candidates](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/19567), though this happens [more often](https://android.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) and I'm not sure if it was a problem for that specific election.

Comment: I don't know if they manually add the dates on the homepage (Or election page), so if they do it was probably extended without their notice or some sort of typo, if it was it would be an easy fix. If it is not manually put in, then I think it is a bug they should fix.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this asked/reported before? Can't find it though... but sure I've seen it :) (Think Adam might have even given some feedback on it...)

Comment: For Android.SE this has been reported here: [Upcoming event will have ended in -7 days](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2473).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I extended the election and I done screwed up. (I thought I had a procedure written down for this, but looking again I don't. Good news: I didn't ignore the process! Bad news: guess I better write it down now.) Fortunately, I was able to make some stickers with the new date:

[image: I voted sticker]

In case it's not clear, I *also* screwed up the end date. It should be on a Tuesday as is tradition and per our process.